# How to Export Data from Microsoft d365 finance and operations using .NET core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dynamics-365

I have found this API : "https://[base URL]/api/connector/dequeue/" for dequeue but I need some reference code for this in C# or .NET Core.
Currently I am sending csv file to `Dynamics 365` by using API for import (enqueue) i.e https://[base URL]/api/connector/enqueue/?entity=.
Now I want once that file process on `Dynamics 365` get the content and save on azure blob .
I am looking for any demo code in c#

Comment: If you using `Dynamics 365`, it is better to give more information about code and context

Comment: Does your `Dynamics365` install on azure ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help.

I had worked for `dynamics 365` (IIS server) about two years ago, so maybe I was wrong or missing something.

But the `dynamics 365` should have a static folder like [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/commerce/upload-serve-static-files)

You should can find a folder in your server that stored your uplaoded files

And maybe you can use the static resource route to get the content.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I want get content from dynamics 365 not upload . For uploading I have already done using enqueue api .

Comment: I mean you need find out where the files stored in your server. And use the static folder resource url to get the content